# cohomology of the thickening

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a local ring with the maximal ideal $m$. Let $X$ be a "good enough" scheme over $A/m^2$ and let $Y = X \times_{Spec(A/m^2)} Spec (A/m).$ In particular, we have the closed immersion $i: Y \to X$. Let $F$ be a quasicoherent sheaf on $X$ and suppose that I know $H^* (Y, i^* F)$. My question is: can I understand $H^* (X, F)$?

The main example I have in mind is $A=\mathbb{Z}_p$. So, in particular $X$ lives mod $p^2$ and $Y$ is its special fiber. I want to have a sequence like $0 \to \bar{F} \to F \to \bar{F} \to 0$ where $\bar{F}$ is the "reduction" of $F$ mod $p$. However, I don't quite see how to construct it. I was thinking to use the short exact sequence associated with the stratification given by this closed subscheme and its complement buy it seems that the complement is something weird..

Comment: Without some flatness such an exact sequence may not exist. Think about $F=i_*G$ for a sheaf $G$ on $Y$.

Comment: @Mohan Right, let us assume this flatness condition

Comment: If $F$ is flat over $A/m^2$, tensor the pull back of the exact sequence $0\to m/m^2\to A/m^2\to A/m\to 0$ with $F$ to get what you want.

Comment: @Mohan Sounds reasonable, thanks!